# Not getting minutes when using datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, timepicker

I am using `jQuery` datetime picker and I want to pick only `time` without `date`, when I click on input I get only `hours`. How I can resolve this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $.datetimepicker.setDateFormatter('moment');
            $(".timepicker").datetimepicker({
                datepicker: false,
                minuteStepping: 15,
                format: 'hh:mm tt',
                pickTime: true,
                defaultDate: new Date(1979, 0, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0),
                language: 'en',
                use24hours: true,
                timeOnly: true,

            });
        })
```

[image: This is what I am getting]

Actually I want to select minutes too, but I don't get that as option.

Comment: which jquery plugin are you using?

Comment: @DanielA.White `https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use their timepicker?

https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/timepicker/